# Type '{ steps: FC<{}>[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }' - React JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to typescript for the below functions typescript gives the following error, tried with `any` which is not recommended, but even with `any` type typescript throws the below error.

`Type '{ steps: FC<{}>[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'. Property 'steps' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)`

I dono how to fix it, please help

```
const DisputeForm: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <TypeForm steps={disputeFormSteps} />
    </>
  );
};

const TypeForm: React.FC = (props:any) => {
  const { steps } = props;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the type of your `steps` prop to be `React.FC` (stands for functional component) array and then specify that there should not be any props by setting the first generic to `Record<PropertyKey, never>`.  Here is this solution in code:

```
import Link from "next/link";

function EmailDispute() {
  return <div>Email Dispute</div>;
}

function UpdateEmailAddress() {
  return <div>Update Email Address</div>;
}

export const disputeFormSteps = [EmailDispute, UpdateEmailAddress];

function DisputeForm() {
  return (
    <>
      <TypeForm steps={disputeFormSteps} />
    </>
  );
}

export default function TypeForm(props: { steps: React.FC<Record<PropertyKey, never>>[] }) {
  const { steps } = props;
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const refs = useRef<(HTMLDivElement | null)[]>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToComponent(refs.current[step]);
  }, [step]);

  return (
    <div>
      {steps
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        .filter((_, index) => index <= step)
        .map((Step, index) => (<Step />))
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFLIBm1xAonXUhnAL5x1QQhwARFFQZBAbgCwAKBl18AOwzAICuExApgAGwAiwQmHyUAFAEpcMuHBEx8UNQB4AJsABuAPg1btcfYeMkRwB6V08paU4ZOUVlVTgAVTBnCiRvHQBBZ2cRQkJzS2lrW3snMI8klMp1TR04LJykPJDyiKjZaSQAD0hYODRVQnhXAMoAMWgQMiQwQjgAXjgAbXS9AyNKbErU1YbcwgBdCJilGBU1fw2kCagQApwrGyQ7BzgTR+tHDw-rOEcAFQAnmBrpM4EMZoR5jgRlcblNKLNuMFvkVfiFUdYzG1otJgsE4M58CAQIDCextDJnBSUCIeLEzvFCGg+NptP8IABhfiQBRIBQwEwAOhFtIA5oQAFxwFAKQFLA5maWywHHTo9aDDJB0FD4bTweSnc5wIEg+EmMB8WbSvAQ62IUQwIVjTmOZADKDORwABStSFggIA0khAdg+W5-R4PAquBYHmiBgohrhwYi5txFpaILMItZE8mlnbsMQYNMwAcFgRiGRUiYAAzYx75+AiOhzRY0eiOEwACX+AFkADL6NxMbRIED8+AAHzgCj12jMCo8JgVjbRNBYbAwJgK8w8hV+4JZEDZHO54FUU5MrcIQrQ9hEAsLiMVua42BfMzfuOKz1Kbw-C47iYkeuB2oQPxHvicBNNowACgAtCMKAAEbjohfJdDAiHwXyUG-EKdA6JQUC7gA+tgCHUl0Fj7nA1HdH8ix2mYBHWEKmhgLuZZUQoNF0QeJiOGWcAomYbFoke7RHi0IGPOu7RAA)

Comment: I still get this error ` The expected type comes from property 'steps' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { steps: FC<Record<PropertyKey, never>>[]; }'`

Comment: @ArunKumar What version of TypeScript are you on? If you checked the playground, it's working for me.

Comment: this is the complete functionality, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-kvyax9

Comment: These errors are coming from ES Lint

Comment: I'm using "typescript": "^4.4.4",

Comment: @ArunKumar I'm on your playground and I don't see any errors.  If ES Lint is throwing than that's linting and unrelated to the actual types / functionality.